# Is it possible to change Google Maps offline background image?

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, offline

I know it might look like a silly question but here is my case :

My app displays detailed overlay over Google Maps. A very simple exemple with this screenshot (The map will be more detailed when the app's released):

[image]

I've noticed that these overlays stay on the view even when there is no connectivity (which is nice):

[image]

My question is, is it possible to change the gray grid background displayed in offline mode?

Comment: Unless there is a method in the MapView class you can call, I highly doubt this is possible.

Comment: afaik no, since that's manages by the map itself - you can check for connectivity and display something instead of the map

Comment: I was afraid so, you can add this as an answer I'll accept it. Cheers guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Mimminito and zapl, it is currently not possible to do that.